# Reason for wave inversion on a string with 2 media?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, waves, string

This question has been partially addressed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147432/why-inversion-of-wave-for-rope-fixed-at-one-end). I use it while stating that Newton's 3rd Law and the action of tension on a string explain why a wave is inverted on encountering a fixed end.

But I fail to understand why this is true for waves which travel on string moving from a lower-higher density. The math itself makes sense (the reflection coefficient, $r<0$) but how would we use Newton's 3rd Law to explain this (if we can use it at all) and why doesn't it happen for a wave motion in a string from higher-lower density?

My best attempt in explaining this would be to correlate the 'higher-lower density motion' phenomenon to that of string attached to a free end & 'lower-higher density motion' phenomenon to that of string attached to a fixed end but this is a guess at best & I'm not able to  get an explanation to the analogy completely.